# Make app notification name different to app name

Tags: ios, notifications

Is it possible to have a different notification name to app name?
E.g 
App name: Mike
Notification name: Tim

Answer (score 2):

**no...** the 'notification app name' is the display name of the app on the springboard.

you CAN have an appstore name different from what you show on springboard only :) [look into CFBundleDisplayname or so for that. might help you too]